# Boundary of union of open subsets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and each $V_i \subset X$ be an open subset of $X$, where $i \in I$. Denote $V_I = \{V_i : i \in I\}$. Below I'll show that

$$(*) \quad \quad \partial \left(\bigcup V_I\right) = \overline{\bigcup \partial V_I} \setminus \bigcup V_I $$

provided

- $X$ is locally connected, or
- $V_I$ is locally finite.

#### The problem

Does this equation hold in arbitrary topological spaces without restrictions? Also of interest are other conditions under which this equation holds.

#### Note

For an arbitrary collection $V_I$ in an arbitrary topological space,

$$\overline{\bigcup \overline{V_I}} = \overline{\bigcup V_I}$$

Hence, we always have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial \left(\bigcup V_I\right) & = \overline{\bigcup V_I} \setminus \bigcup V_I \\
{} & = \overline{\bigcup \overline{V_I}} \setminus \bigcup V_I \\
{} & \supset \overline{\bigcup \partial V_I} \setminus \bigcup V_I 
\end{aligned}
$$

#### Theorem A

Let $X$ be a topological space, $U, V \subset X$ both be open, and $U$ be connected. Then $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$ and $U \setminus V \neq \emptyset$ if and only if $U \cap \partial V \neq \emptyset$.

#### Proof A

Suppose $U \cap \partial V = \emptyset$. Then $U = (U \cap V) \cup (U \setminus \overline{V})$, and these subsets are disjoint. Since $U$ is connected, either $U \cap V = \emptyset$, or $U \setminus \overline{V} = \emptyset$. Because of the assumption, the latter is equivalent to $U \setminus V = \emptyset$. Suppose $U \cap \partial V \neq \emptyset$. Then $U \cap \overline{V} \cap \overline{X \setminus V} \neq \emptyset$, which implies $U \cap \overline{V} \neq \emptyset$ and $U \cap \overline{X \setminus V} \neq \emptyset$. Since $U$ is open, $U \cap \overline{V} = \emptyset \iff U \cap V \neq \emptyset$. Since $V$ is open, $U \setminus V = U \cap (X \setminus V) = U \cap \overline{X \setminus V} \neq \emptyset$.

#### Theorem B

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a locally connected topological space, and $V_I$ be as in the problem description. Then $(*)$ holds.

#### Proof B

Let $U = \bigcup V_I$, and denote by $\mathcal{T}^*(x)$ the connected open neighborhoods of $x$. By Theorem A,
$$
\begin{aligned}
{} & x \in \partial U \\
\iff & x \in \overline{U} \setminus U \\
\iff & x \in \overline{\bigcup V_I} \setminus U \\
\iff & \forall W \in \mathcal{T}^*(x) : W \cap \bigcup V_I \neq \emptyset \land x \in X \setminus U \\
\iff & \forall W \in \mathcal{T}^*(x) : \exists i \in I: W \cap V_i \neq \emptyset \land x \in X \setminus U \\
\iff & \forall W \in \mathcal{T}^*(x) : \exists i \in I: W \cap V_i \neq \emptyset \land W \setminus V_i \neq \emptyset \land x \in X \setminus U \\
\iff & \forall W \in \mathcal{T}^*(x) : \exists i \in I: W \cap \partial V_i \neq \emptyset \land x \in X \setminus U \\
\iff & x \in \overline{\bigcup \partial V_I} \setminus U.
\end{aligned}
$$

#### Theorem C

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, and $V_I$ be as in the problem description, and also locally finite. Then $(*)$ holds.

#### Proof C

Let $U = \bigcup V_I$. For a locally finite collection (open subset or not), it holds that

$$\overline{\bigcup V_I} = \bigcup \overline{V_I}.$$

Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial U & = \overline{U} \setminus U \\
{} & = \overline{\bigcup V_I} \setminus U \\
{} & = \bigcup \overline{V_I} \setminus U \\
{} & = \bigcup \{\overline{V_i} : i \in I\} \setminus U \\
{} & = \bigcup \{\overline{V_i} \setminus V_i : i \in I\} \setminus U \\
{} & = \bigcup \partial V_I \setminus U \\
{} & = \overline{\bigcup \partial V_I} \setminus U.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: You could get a counterexample if each $V_i$ has empty boundary, but their union does not.

Comment: Good idea. Now to think of one:)

Comment: In a space where open sets are exactly the closed sets, open sets do not have boundaries. I wonder if that behavior could somehow be localized.

Comment: Hmm. Let $X = \{1/i : i \in \mathbb{N}^{>0}\} \cup \{0\}$. Let $V_i = (1/i-1/(4i),1/i+1/(4i)) \cap X$. Then $V_i \subset X$ is open, $\partial V_i = \emptyset$, and $\partial \bigcup V_I = \{0\}$. Unless I miss something, that's a simple counterexample.

Comment: Yep that does it. For some reason I was thinking $\partial \{ x \} = \{ x \}$. Also see my example in Cantor space below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counterexample as per my comment. Let $X = 2^\omega$ be Cantor space with the usual topology, generated by basic clopen sets $[\sigma] = \{ \sigma^\frown \alpha: \alpha \in 2^\omega \}$ for finite strings $\sigma \in 2^{<\omega}$. Let $U \subseteq 2^\omega$ be any open set which is not closed (examples of such things [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54866/cantor-space-example-of-an-open-set-thats-not-closed), e.g. the complement of a point). Then, $U = \bigcup_{i \in I} V_i$ for some basic $V_i$.

We use the fact that $A \subseteq X$ clopen $\iff$ $\partial A = \varnothing$. $U$ is not clopen, so $\partial U \neq \varnothing$. However, all the $V_i$ are clopen, so $\bigcup_{i \in I} \partial V_i = \varnothing$. It follows that $\partial U \neq \overline{\bigcup_{i \in I} \partial V_i} \setminus \bigcup_{i \in I} V_i$.

Presumably this works because Cantor space fails badly to be satisfy any sort of connectedness - it is totally disconnected.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and this answer. What is the arc-thingy in the definition of $[\sigma]$?

Comment: Oh, string concatenation

Comment: A basic open set is the set all strings extending a given finite binary string $\sigma$

Comment: This certainly answers the question. I'll still leave the question open for some time, in hope of getting answers about when exactly the equation holds. In particular, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not locally connected, but my intuition says the equation should hold there. But why?

Comment: Huh, seems that was just bad intuition. Let $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ be a decreasing sequence of irrational numbers which converge to 0. Let $V_i = (x_{i + 1}, x_1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Then $V_i \subset \mathbb{Q}$ are open, $\partial V_i = \emptyset$, and $\partial \bigcup V_I = \{0\}$.

Comment: My conjecture is that the equation is in fact equivalent to local connectedness. That the failure of local connectedness allows to construct such counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a zero-dimensional space (i.e. it has a base of clopen sets) and let $U$  be open in $X$ but not closed.

Then write $U = \bigcup\{ U_i: i \in I\}$ where all $U_i$ are clopen. Then $\partial V_i = \emptyset$, so $\bigcup_i \partial V_i = \emptyset$ so the right hand side of your identity reduces to $\emptyset$ while te let hand side is just $\partial U \neq \emptyset$.

Such sets $U$ exist in $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$, the Cantor set, and in fact in most zero-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show that the property (*) in the question implies locally connected, and hence that (*) is equivalent to local connectedness.

By contraposition, suppose $X$ is not locally connected. Then there exists $U \in \mathcal{T}$ such that $U$ is not sum-connected (meaning not all components are open). By this [excellent recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4634139/51161), $\mathcal{T}|U \cap \mathcal{T}^C|U$ is not a topology, which in turn by the theorem in that question is equivalent to there existing $V \in_I \mathcal{T}|U$ such that $\partial_U {V_i} = \emptyset$, but $\partial_U (\bigcup V) \neq \emptyset$.

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
{} && (\overline{\bigcup \partial_X V_i}(X) \setminus \bigcup V) \cap U \\
= && \overline{\bigcup \partial_X V_i \cap U}(U) \setminus \bigcup V \\ 
= && \overline{\bigcup \partial_U V_i}(U) \setminus \bigcup V \\ 
= && \emptyset.
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
{} && \partial_X (\bigcup V) \cap U \\
= && \partial_U (\bigcup V \cap U) \\
= && \partial_U (\bigcup V) \\
\neq && \emptyset.
\end{eqnarray}

Hence

$$\partial_X (\bigcup V) \neq \overline{\bigcup \partial_X V_i}(X) \setminus \bigcup V).$$

Above we used the facts that $\partial_X A \cap U = \partial_U (A \cap U)$ for any $A \subset X$ and $U \in \mathcal{T}$. Similarly $\overline{A}(X) \cap U = \overline{A \cap U}(U)$ for any $A \subset X$ and $U \in \mathcal{T}$.